# why java program runs perfectly even without using volatile variable?

Tags: java, operating-system, volatile

I know very well what volatile variable is, but, I have never seen any setup that failed, if volatile is not used. 
As per the accepted answer's case in thread([Do you ever use the volatile keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java)), tried replicating the setup, but program works perfectly fine. See below.

```
class VolatileTest extends Thread{
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public void run(){
        while(isRunning){
            System.out.println("volatile test");
        }
    }

}

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        VolatileTest volatileTest = new VolatileTest();
        volatileTest.start();

        Thread.sleep(2000l);
        volatileTest.isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

One thread runs and prints "volatile test" if isRunning is true(I was in assumption it will be cached). In main thread I am changing the value of isRunning. Here, other thread is able to read change after 2 sec. This setup never failed.

My question is:

1. How this is working? is native OS doesn't allow caching?
2. Is there any example I can get which actually fails?